# A Diagonal DIV in another DIV

Tags: html, css

Sorry for my english.

I have a problem. I need to create a DIV inside another DIV, which has to have a white background. I tried using skew, but It didnt work well.

Here is an image:

[image: White Diagonal Div]

Comment: Could you show us some code? with what you have tried? or perhaps a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: will do now. Will edit the post

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BKfe9/

Comment: It is a tricky problem, which requires a tricky answer. I'm not writing this as an answer because it isn't the most ideal. But I would recommend just using a background image which has that diagonal cut out. Maybe use an SVG so it can scale to whatever size.

Comment: That's the best bet... using an image... a PNG probably?

Comment: reminds me of http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/ALlks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least several ways to achieve this, however the simplest way may be using linear-gradient background. Its quality is not really good compared with others but it's totally acceptable.

Try this:

```
div {
  width:600px;
  height:300px;
  background:teal;
  border:1px solid teal;
}
.top {    
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  font-size:25px;
  padding-left:30px;
  background:linear-gradient(175deg, white 60%, transparent 62%);
  border:none;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div>
  <div class='top'>Custom<br/>Home</div>
</div>
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sL945/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Exactly this!! Genious!

Comment: @King King as you said there are other ways as well. Is it possible using `transform: skewY`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey theoretically it's possible, however the text is also be transformed. I would use `rotate` instead. However you have to wrap the text inside another container, we rotate the div, then we have to rotate the inside container backwards so that the text is not rotated.

Comment: @KingKing or rotate a pseudo element so it doesn't afect the text.

Comment: okay for example in this case http://jsbin.com/ruginoce/1/edit.. how to skew on any specific angle?

Comment: @user3675890 be aware that linear gradients aren't supported by IE9- http://caniuse.com/css-gradients

Comment: @web-tiki I also thought of rendering the `:before` or `:after` as the background while keeping the text unchanged, however looks like you separate 2 divs, while as the OP said, one div should be nested in another div. That's the situation in which we may have difficulty to set the `z-index` so that the `:before` is shown behind the text, while it should be above/over the outer container.

Comment: @KingKing I don't really understand what you mean there is no issue in specifying a z-index on the pseudo element to show it behind the content and still overflow the parent div to make the diagonal line. Anyway it seems OP had changed his mind because in the fiddle he posted no more div nesting...

Comment: @web-tiki I have successfully set the `z-index` in which we use only 2 divs (one is nested in another) http://jsfiddle.net/sL945/5/ Here we have to set `position:relative` to the outer container and also set `z-index:-1` (or some more negative) for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with a pseudo element and transform rotate :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/3Kpj5/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div id="header">
    Custom<br/>
    Home
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
#header{
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    z-index:1;
    font-size:30px;
    padding-left:10%; 
}
#header:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:110%;
    height:1000%;
    background:inherit;
    z-index:-1;
    border-bottom:2px solid #636A6E;

    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* to fix pixelisation in chrome */


    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin:100% 100%;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);


}
#content{
    min-height:500px;
    background:#778385;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the border in your diagonal div, try this:

CSS:

```
.logo {
    width:110%;
    height:147px;
    top:-10%;
    left:-14px;
    border:2px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    transform:rotate(-7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-7deg);
    /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:612px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#7b8284;
    position:relative;
}
.inner {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;
    transform:rotate(7deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(7deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(7deg);
    /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
    padding:20px 90px;
    top:30%;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
        <div class="inner">My Logo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/BKfe9/1/

You can modify the top,left,font-size,background-color,transform, border as per your need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in pure CSS I would recommend using the `transform: rotate(xxx)` feature of CSS3. I've created a JS-Fiddle that will help you get started (not the best solution...), it is not based on your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/syTu7/

Comment: The only problem with this would be the text also rotates, so you would have to then rotate the elements within it, back the other way.

Comment: Yup I did this in the `div#text`. As I said, it may not be the best solution but it works as a start. Maybe you can build up on this.

Comment: That actually helps more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your question, I think my example will help

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="innter">some text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
.innter {
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ececec;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a short description about how your example will help?

Answer (score -2):

In HTML,

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="inner">some content</div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.inner {
background: #fff;     
}
```

Comment: How does this make it with a diagonal line/div?

Comment: I mean... that is newbie. Check out the picture.

Comment: You mean to say, a diagonal div? or a div inside another div?

Comment: A diagonal div inside another div.

Comment: or a diagonal div and after a normal div